# Flutter - setState not updating Widgets?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to build a Reviews section for my app. In that, I'm trying to have a read more feature which obviously as the name suggests will expand the widget to show more text, upon tapping the widget.
I'm using a indexed stack with BottomNavigationBar to switch between reviews and the product page.

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
import 'Product_Page_Widgets.dart';
void main() => runApp(Product());
class Product extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ProductState(),
    );
  }
}
class ProductState extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<dynamic,dynamic> productData;
  CollectionReference reviews;
  ProductState({@required this.productData,@required this.reviews});
  @override
  _ProductStateState createState() => _ProductStateState();
}

class _ProductStateState extends State<ProductState>  with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  List<NetworkImage> _Images = [];
  List<Widget> productImages = [];
  List<Widget> reviewWidgets = [];
  String changeableText = "";
  List<String> firstHalf = [];
  List<String> secondHalf = [];
  var cardHeight = [];

  bool load  = false;

  int pageIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> pageWidget = [];
  addPageWidgets() async{
    pageWidget.add( ProductPageWidget(
        productName: widget.productData['Name'],
        galleryItems: _Images,cachedImages: productImages,description:widget.productData['description'] ?? "placeholder")

    );
    Widget w =  await buildReviewsWidgets();
    pageWidget.add(w);

  }
  GlobalKey key = new GlobalKey();
 Future <Widget> buildReviewsWidgets() async{

    var docs = await widget.reviews.getDocuments();
    var documents = docs.documents;

      print(documents.toString());
    if(docs != null) {

      for (int i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
        cardHeight.add(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4);
        print(documents[i].data['Review']);
       if(documents[i].data['Review'].toString().length>50){
         firstHalf.add( documents[i].data['Review'].toString().substring(0,50));
         secondHalf.add(documents[i].data['Review'].toString().substring(51));

       }else{
         firstHalf.add( documents[i].data['Review'].toString());
          secondHalf.add("");

       }


      }



    }
    for(var doc in documents){
      print(doc.data);

    }


  return Container(
        height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: ListView.builder(
          key: key,
          itemCount: documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index) => AnimatedSize(
            vsync: this,
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
            duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: Container(
              height: cardHeight[index],
              child: Card(

                elevation: 2.0,

                child: ListTile(
                  onTap: (){
                    stateUpdate(index);
                  },
                    leading: CircleAvatar(),
                    title: Text(documents[index].data['Title']),

                    subtitle: Column(children: [

                      RatingBar(
                        itemBuilder: (context, _) => Icon(
                          Icons.star,
                          color: Colors.amber,
                        ),
                        maxRating: 5.0,
                        allowHalfRating: false,
                        ignoreGestures: true,
                        initialRating: int.parse(documents[index].data['Rating'].toString()).toDouble(),
                      ),
                      Wrap(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(firstHalf[index].toString()),
                          Text("Read More")
                        ],
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ),

              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

}
void AddNetworkImages (BuildContext context){
  if(!load) {

    for (int i = 0; i < widget.productData.length; i++) {
      if (widget.productData.containsKey('Img$i')) {
        print("Img$i exists");
        _Images.add(
            NetworkImage(widget.productData['Img$i'])
        );
        productImages.add(
          CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: widget.productData['Img$i'],
            placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),

          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
void loadWidgets(BuildContext context){
  setState(() {

  });
  load = true;

}
  @override
  void initState() {
    //AddNetworkImages(context);
    addPageWidgets();

    super.initState();



  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => AddNetworkImages(context));

    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => loadWidgets(context));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        actions: <Widget>[

        ],
        title: Text("$changeableText"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(

      ),

          child:IndexedStack(
            index: pageIndex,
            children: pageWidget,
          )),
      bottomNavigationBar:BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            pageIndex = index;

          });
        },

        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(

            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            title: Text("Overview")
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            title: Text("Reviews")
          )
        ],
      )
    );
}

  void stateUpdate(int index) {
    setState(() {
      firstHalf[index]+=secondHalf[index];
      cardHeight[index] = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2;

    });
    print(index);
    print(firstHalf[index]);
  }
}
```

Now, inside the buildReviewsWidgets() method, i'm getting all of the review data ,iterating over it and splitting it into the firstHalf and secondHalf lists, so that, on tapping the ListTile, i can simply join firstHalf[index] and secondHalf[index], as i have done so  on the ontap method of the ListTiles, but tapping on the list tile does nothing at all..the list tiles don't update, basically nothing happens. But whats interesting is that if I setState and change the value of changeableText, it does update the text on the appbar.. can anyone tell me why this is happening? how do i fix it?

Comment: `Widget w =  await buildReviewsWidgets();` what do you want to achieve with that? if you have some `Future` use `FutureBuilder`, not things like that...

Comment: There is a lot going on here, and the code is formatted in a way that makes it very hard to visually parse through and understand what you have going on. My first guess, though, would be that `setState` is triggering a rebuild of your widget just fine, but the things you are updating wouldn't result in any visible changes.

Comment: @pskink if you look at that method, you'll see that it's  fetching documents and building the widget with accordance to the same.

Comment: @pskink actually, I didn't think I'd need it because I don't need to get a constant source of information that will be updated every time.

Comment: @Abion47 inside the ListView.builder, you can see that the ListTile's  subtitle property is set to a Text widget with firstHalf[index] passed as the string, and on the onTap method, im calling another method that does uses setState to update the firstHalf[index] 's value.. would that not be enough to trigger a rebuild?

Comment: You are updating the value based on the value of `secondHalf[index]`. Are you sure that isn't 0 or something? (We can't see that data.)

Comment: absolutely positive that secondHalf[index] isn't a null or empty, because in the log i can see the full text of firstHalf[index] + secondHalf[index]

Comment: Then between the poor/inconsistent formatting and not knowing what the values of your data actually are, this is a very problematic question for anyone to be able to answer. I'd suggest reducing your problem to a [mcve] so that people can more easily digest your code and detect the problem.  (You may even discover the problem yourself in doing so.)

Comment: @Abion47 I guess I'll just have to rewrite things, but this could potentially be an obscure framework bug.

Comment: While I don't want to say it's impossible, it is _extremely_ unlikely for that to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I just cleaned the code up and removed the need of storing widgets with lists..not involving any lists with the widgets instantly fixed the problem.